# Django - reloading element through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to alter selection options on the page dynamically without reloading the page. The alteration shall depend on id received from dynamically value of element on the same page. I am trying to use AJAX for this but the element fails to be dynamically updated. I wish I could render this update through the back end.

models.py

```
class Exptype(models.Model):
  exp_type = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  def __unicode__(self):
  return self.exp_type

class Subtype(models.Model):
  exptype = models.ForeignKey(Exptype, related_name= 'exptypes')
  exp_subtype = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  def __unicode__(self):
  return self.exp_subtype

class Payer(models.Model):
  exp_payer = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  def __unicode__(self):
  return self.exp_payer
```

views.py

```
def recording(request):   
   typex = Exptype.objects.all()
   subtype = Subtype.objects.all()
   payer = Payer.objects.all()

   if request.is_ajax():
      expval = int(request.POST.get("formdata", ""))
      subtype = Subtype.objects.filter(exptype=expval)

    return render(request, 'expenses/recording.html', {
                    'subtype': subtype,
                })


return render(request, 'expenses/recording.html', {
                    'payer': payer,
                    'typex': typex,
                    'subtype': subtype,
            })
```

recording.html

```
<td id="OnType">
        <select id="expval" name="expsubmit">
            {% for exp in typex %} 
            <option value="{{ exp.id }}">{{ exp }}</option>
            {% endfor %}    
        </select>   
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Subtype</th>
    <th>Payer</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="OnStype">
        <select id="subval" name="recordsub">
            {% for sub in subtype %}
            <option value="{{ sub.id }}">{{ sub }}</option>
              {# this list of values here shall change depending on selection of #expval #}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </td>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

ajaxscr.js

```
$("#OnStype").on("mouseenter", function() {
    expval = $("#expval").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/expenses/recording/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        formdata: expval,
        },
        success: function() {
            $("#result").html(expval); //checking the ajax call
        }
    });
});
```

Got POST response from the console and it is correct. But anyway the DOM element stayed outdated. What could it be?

*POST response:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 (...)
    <td id="OnType">
        <select id="expval" name="expsubmit">

        </select>   
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th id="OnStype">Subtype</th>
    <th>Payer</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="subval" name="recordsub">
            <option value="3">Fruit</option>
            <option value="4">Meat</option>
            <option value="5">Juice</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

Comment: How is it failing? Assuming your AJAX is valid and being used by the page with the right ids, this should work fine. Does the developer console say anything when attempting to query things? (Might be nice to see your JS/AJAX code too)

Comment: Where is your AJAX code?

Comment: @AaronLayfield, you are right, I should public ajax code first - please look post updated. Console returns POST normally, JSON returns ID and result message fine. I don't have a clue what might be wrong.

Comment: @Yaaaaaaaaaaay, updated.

Comment: @Vyachez replace ".html(expval)" to ".html(json)"

Comment: @Yaaaaaaaaaaay thank you, but I deleted JSON call back to DOM. The problem is in other place, please see updated post.

Comment: @Vyachez no, edit it back because in the succes function has to be inside the brackets a param where the data from the server will be stored. My advice for you is to put, where is possible, print() and alert() or console.log() statements for checking what part of your code is wrong.

Comment: Any other ideas? I am writing json response iteration function to extract values form queryset and push them to DOM, but this solution seems quite bulky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating view context - won't update DOM element. This is AJAX job. The conclusion - the data should be passed via JSON back from the view to JavaScript.js. Here parts of code fixed:

views.py

```
def recording(request):   
  typex = Exptype.objects.all().values('id', 'exp_type')
  payer = Payer.objects.all()

  if request.is_ajax():
    var = int(request.POST.get("expvalue", ""))
    subt = serializers.serialize('json', Subtype.objects.filter(exptype=var), fields=('exp_subtype'))        
    response_data = {}
    try:
        response_data['result'] = 'ok - submit'
        response_data['message'] = subt
    except:
        response_data['result'] = 'Failure'
        response_data['result'] = 'the script failed'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")

return render(request, 'expenses/recording.html', {
                    'payer': payer,
                    'typex': typex,
            })
```

ajaxcode.js

```
$("#expval").on('change', function() {
    $('#subval').html('');
    expval = $("#expval").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/expenses/recording/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        expvalue: expval,
        },
        success: function(json) {
            var expfilter = json.message
            var dat = JSON.parse(expfilter);
            //going extracting value of required Object
            //console.log(expfilter)
            for (fields in dat){
                if (dat.hasOwnProperty(fields)) {
                    var dd = dat[fields]
                    var v_first = true;
                    //console.log(dd)
                    for (i in dd) {
                        if (dd.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            if (v_first) {
                                var obj = dd[i]
                                //console.log(obj)
                                v_first = false;
                                var first = true;
                                for (x in obj) {
                                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                                        if (first) {
                                            console.log(obj[x]);
                                            var subt = obj[x]
                                            //appending selection with extracted values
                                            $('<option/>', { value : subt }).text(subt).appendTo('#subval');
                                            first = false;
                                            }
                                        }                                
                                    }
                               }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }         
    })
})
```

recording.html

```
<tr><td id="OnType">
        <select id="expval" name="recordtype">
              <option selected="true" style="display:none;">Select Type</option>
            {% for exp in typex %} 
            <option value={{ exp.id }}>{{ exp.exp_type }}</option>
            {% endfor %}    
        </select>   
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="subval" name="recordsub">

        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```